# Pass data from view razor page to action method in controller

Tags: jquery, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I need to pass data from this razor page view:

[image]

To this action method:

[image]

I want my data being sent to an action on page load.

How to implement this?

Comment: Your method is not an 'action' in terms of ASP.NET MVC. It must return ActionResult

Comment: Yes it's my mistake it have ti return ActionResult ,thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use Ajax & jQuery to push data to the server:

### Javascript

```
$(function() { // on page load
    $.post({ //do ajax post request
        url: '/OauthCallBack/GmailOAuthCallback',
        data: 'code=' + someCode, //your data 
        success: function () {
            //Success callback if necessary
        }
    })
});
```

### Controller

```
public class OauthCallBackController : Controller
{
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult GmailOAuthCallback(string code)
    {
        //Do something

        return new EmptyResult(); //or return anything :)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Andrej.Just for a knowledge is there enother way to implement it using HTMLHELPER class?

Comment: @Michael, Probably you can wrap is with inline HTML helper notation. Take a look http://www.dotnet-tricks.com/Tutorial/mvc/N50P050314-Understanding-HTML-Helpers-in-ASP.NET-MVC.html

Comment: I have some problem to use HTML Helper the view razor page.When I try to use for example this row: 
|@Html.BeginForm()
I get this error:

Error 1 'System.Web.WebPages.Html.HtmlHelper' does not contain a definition for 'BeginForm' and the best extension method overload 'System.Web.Mvc.Html.FormExtensions.BeginForm(System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper)' has some invalid arguments.

When I remove this inharitance row:
@inherits System.Web.WebPages.WebPage

The error disappeared.
Do you  have any idea  why the inherits cause to error?